# 2d perspective skew in JS

Tags: javascript, 2d, perspective

I want to transform an image in 2 points perspective.

I guess I need to transfer to JS a formula from: [http://web.iitd.ac.in/~hegde/cad/lecture/L9_persproj.pdf](http://web.iitd.ac.in/%7Ehegde/cad/lecture/L9_persproj.pdf)
But I'm humanities-minded person and I faint when I see matrices.

Here's what I need exactly:
I have a two vanishing points: X(X.x, X.y) and Z(Z.x, Z.y). And rectangle ABCD (A.x, A.y and so on)
[image]
<sub>(source: [take.ms](http://take.ms/hELQY))</sub>

And I want to find new nA, nB, nC and nD points with which I can transform my rectangle like that (the points order doesn't really matter):
[image]
<sub>(source: [take.ms](http://take.ms/MkdZQ))</sub>

Right now I'm doing weird approximate calculations: I'm looking for most distant point from X (1), then lay over an interval towards Z (2), than another interval towards X (3) and then again from Z (4):

[image]
<sub>(source: [take.ms](http://take.ms/QL9At))</sub>

The result is a bit off but is alright for the precision I need, but this algorithm sometimes gives very weird results if I change vanishing points, so if there's a proper solution I'll gladly use it. Thanks!